# Active HTML button on navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have been researching lately on how to do this but i have really not been able to find a good way to do this for my html + css navbar. Basically when you are on the homepage of the site, the tab color needs to be "active" or frozen as a different color. Right now as you can see in  the jsfiddle when you hover over the navbar button it will change a different color until you take your mouse off of it. My question might be hard to understand my apologies.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jyh715yn/

Thanks for the help!

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<img src="/Users/alexparsons/Desktop/AvoArt/img/logo2.jpg" style="left: 10px; margin: 0     auto; ">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Request Order</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

</body>




</html>


img {

  left: 10px;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto; }
nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0; }
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden; }
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%; }
nav ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  
    #fff 0%, #fff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
    color-stop(0%,#fff), 
    color-stop(100%,#fff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  
    #fff 0%,#fff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  
    #fff 0%,#fff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  
    #fff 0%,#fff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
    startColorstr='#fff', 
    endColorstr='#fff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  }
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:focus,
nav ul li a:visited,
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:active {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none; }
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:active {
  background: #D3D3D3; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  
    #D3D3D3 0%, #D3D3D3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
    color-stop(0%,#D3D3D3), 
    color-stop(100%,#D3D3D3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  
    #D3D3D3 0%,#D3D3D3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  
    #D3D3D3 0%,#D3D3D3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  
    #D3D3D3 0%,#D3D3D3 100%); /* W3C, IE10+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
    startColorstr='#000', 
    endColorstr='#000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  }
nav ul li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px; }
nav ul li:last-child a {
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; }
```

Comment: Please post the javascript file you are using.

Comment: Is your page in ajax (without refreshing?)

Comment: Is this page being generated by PHP or any server side language?

Comment: I have not added any javascript file but i an create one. There is no php at the moment. I basically have to files in my root.

Comment: With just the HTML you've given us, it's a little hard for us to be able to know exactly how your system is going to pan out in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, without knowing where your system will go in the future, it's a little hard to know exactly how to code this. With links that are solely hash symbols, it's unclear whether or not the links will be on the page or to another webpage.

Normally if your pages are being generated in PHP, you would simply put code to check the file being displayed and add a class of "active", which contains all of your CSS rules for the active element, to that particular element.

But without that knowledge, I've got something working below. If you click on any of the links, it should display a block, like it does for the hover effect, on that element until another element is clicked.

I used the hashtag formatting and the CSS `:target` attribute. With a bit more information I could probably help you more, but with only the given HTML, I got working what I could.

### Downsides of this method

It is going to keep scrolling the user up to the top, due to the usage of hash links. This may or may not result in a noticable sort of "jump" upon interaction, depending on the rest of the contents of your web page.

```css
img {
  left: 10px;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #fff 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(100%, #fff));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #fff 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #fff 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff', endColorstr='#fff', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:focus,
nav ul li a:visited,
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:active {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:active,
nav ul li:target a {
  background: #D3D3D3;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D3D3D3 0%, #D3D3D3 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #D3D3D3), color-stop(100%, #D3D3D3));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D3D3D3 0%, #D3D3D3 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #D3D3D3 0%, #D3D3D3 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #D3D3D3 0%, #D3D3D3 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000', endColorstr='#000', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
}
nav ul li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
nav ul li:last-child a {
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<img src="/Users/alexparsons/Desktop/AvoArt/img/logo2.jpg" style="left: 10px; margin: 0 auto; ">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="home">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="gallery">
      <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li id="about">
      <a href="#about">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li id="request">
      <a href="#request">Request Order</a>
    </li>
    <li id="contact">
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```